# Nib is automatically being added to the screen

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, xib

I have a nib file I'm trying to instantiate in code. My UIViewController's main view is also loaded from a nib file.

Here's my UIViewController's viewDidLoad method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyCustomView" bundle:nil];
    NSArray *nibViews = [nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
    MyCustomView *myView = [nibViews objectAtIndex:0];
    myView.frame = CGRectMake(100.0f, 100.0f, 91.0f, 91.0f);
    [self.view addSubview:myView];
}
```

This creates some sort of endless loop. If I comment out [self.view addSubview:myView], myView appears, but everything currently on the screen disappears. I didn't think instantiateWithOwner added the view to the screen. If it does, how do I get access to it?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you declaring a XIB name in Interface Builder as well as in code? I think you get a warning if you do this but it will compile.

Comment: Both my .h/.m file (the code behind for the nib) and the nib have the same name. It's basically something like: MyCustomView.h, MyCustomView.m, MyCustomView.xib. This isn't a problem though, and it seems the be the general way people do it.

Comment: That's not what I meant. In your MainWindow.xib, if you have set your custom view to a view controller (which is one way of doing it). Then you should then add a subview with the nib in. You'll end up with an infinite loop of subviews doing it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `instantiateWithOwner` method reassigns the properties of your view controller (set from the nib the controller was created from) to ones from the new nib. Those properties likely include the `view` property, so that method, within it, contains a call to `setView:`, and sets the view controller's view to the new nib's view. Afterwards, you're trying to add a view as a subview to itself, and that, naturally, causes problems.

You want to create your own property, for instance, `secondaryView`, set the nib's view to that, and add it as a subview. You don't want to reassign your view controller's view.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "set the nib's view to that". I can't set the nib's view in Interface Builder to a property in my UIViewController unless that view controller is my nib's File's Owner. Is there no way to instantiate a nib without overriding my view controller's current view?

Comment: Pass in nil to `instantiateWithOwner:options:` for both parameters.